# What is task-loss function?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, measurement-error

I looked into ["Multi-Output Learning for Camera Relocalization"](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/220080/cvpr14_multiple_predictors.pdf) research and faced with the following part (2.2 The Direct Regression Approach):

> Given a set of RGB-D frames with known camera poses S = {(Ij , Hj ):
>   j ∈ [n]}, we want to learn a mapping g, taking an RGB-D frame as
>   argument and predicting a 6 d.o.f. camera pose, such that the the
>   empirical risk is minimized
>
> $$ L(\Theta;S)=\frac 1 n \sum_{j=1}^n l(H_j,g(I_j,\Theta)) $$
>
> Here, the task-loss $l$ measures the error between the ground-truth
>   pose $H_j$ and the predictor’s output $g(I_j; \Theta)$, and $\Theta$
>   is the set of parameters to be learned.

So, my question is -- what is task-loss $l$?

Is it any appropriate function for error measurement?

Actually, the question is about terminology but the form of the function $l$.

Comment: Maybe the loss function depends on the task the algorithm is used for? Generally, loss functions connect mathematical presentation and practical use.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch Is task-loss function the same as [loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function)?

Comment: I do not understand why they use that term. It is a loss function in the standard sense of the term. As you cite, the refer to the empirical risk minimization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization).

Comment: Task loss is a "task-specific" loss. You can call it just a loss function, but some people might get confused. Hence, people started using the term "task loss" to show that the actual function depends on a task at hand. For example, If you are training a network with multiple heads, the regression head would have (for example) an MSE, while the classification head would have a 0-1 loss, etc.